Error code 8: attempt to write a readonly database (SQLite3)
I'm using the new expo sqlite package and I have the following code:
Code in the app.tsx
const configDatabase = async () => {
    const dbName = "test.db";
    const dbAsset = require("./assets/DB/test.db");
    const dbUri = Asset.fromModule(dbAsset).uri;
    const dbFilePath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/${dbName}`;

    try {
        const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(dbFilePath);

        if (fileInfo.exists) {
            await FileSystem.deleteAsync(dbFilePath);
        }

        await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
            `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/`,
            { intermediates: true }
        );

        await FileSystem.downloadAsync(dbUri, dbFilePath);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

Code in my input screen
const db = useSQLiteContext();

async function submitHandler() {
        const statement = await db.prepareAsync(
            'INSERT INTO test (itemId, itemName, itemDescription, itemImagePath, itemIsMovie) VALUES ($itemId, $itemName, $itemDescription, $itemImagePath, $itemIsMovie)'
        );

        const result = await statement.executeAsync({$itemId: item['id'], $itemName: item[movie ? 'title' : 'name'], $itemDescription: item['overview'], $itemImagePath: item['poster_path'], $itemIsMovie: movie})
        console.log(`Result added: ${result.lastInsertRowId} - ${result.changes}`)
    }

But when I insert the values I get the error that I can't write into a readonly database, but I have no idea how I can change this.
How I created my DB which sits in the following location ./assets/DB/test.db
>sqlite3 test.db
>PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
>CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, itemId TEXT NOT NULL, itemName TEXT NOT NULL, itemDescription TEXT NOT NULL, itemImagePath TEXT, itemIsMovie INTEGER NOT NULL);

